# Problem searching domain with elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, term-query

I have registered the following document

```
"ownDomainValue":"catalogonuevo1.com"
```

When I perform the following query the document is found, value is "catalogonuevo1"

```
[
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "valor_dominio_propio": "catalogonuevo1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "from": 0,
        "size": 1
    }
]
```

However, when the search value is "catalogonuevo1.com"

```
[
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "valor_dominio_propio": "catalogonuevo1.com"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "from": 0,
        "size": 1
    }
]
```

it does not return any value, using MatchQueries the opposite happens, it always finds a wrong document, such as one with the value "catalogonuevo2.com" which is not what I am looking for since I need the search to be exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that the "term" query in Elasticsearch is not matching the exact value "catalogonuevo1.com" when it is included in the query.

This is likely because the "term" query is tokenizing the input string at the "." character, so it is matching on the token "catalogonuevo1" rather than the entire string "catalogonuevo1.com".

You can resolve this issue by using the "match_phrase" query instead of "term" query, as "match_phrase" query matches on the exact phrase rather than individual tokens.

Additionally, you can use keyword fields to store the domain values; this way, the values are not tokenized and the match phrase will work as expected.